# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 103: invalid start byte

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I downloaded this code from https://github.com/tensorflow/models

And I'm having a error like this.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 103: invalid start byte

line 103 is 'strategy = tf.compat.v2.distribute.MirroredStrategy()'

How can I solve this problem?

---

```
from absl import flags
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
from object_detection import model_lib_v2

flags.DEFINE_string('pipeline_config_path', None, 'Path to pipeline config '
                    'file.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_train_steps', None, 'Number of train steps.')
flags.DEFINE_bool('eval_on_train_data', False, 'Enable evaluating on train '
                  'data (only supported in distributed training).')
flags.DEFINE_integer('sample_1_of_n_eval_examples', None, 'Will sample one of '
                     'every n eval input examples, where n is provided.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples', 5, 'Will sample '
                     'one of every n train input examples for evaluation, '
                     'where n is provided. This is only used if '
                     '`eval_training_data` is True.')
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'model_dir', None, 'Path to output model directory '
                       'where event and checkpoint files will be written.')
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'checkpoint_dir', None, 'Path to directory holding a checkpoint.  If '
    '`checkpoint_dir` is provided, this binary operates in eval-only mode, '
    'writing resulting metrics to `model_dir`.')

flags.DEFINE_integer('eval_timeout', 3600, 'Number of seconds to wait for an'
                     'evaluation checkpoint before exiting.')

flags.DEFINE_bool('use_tpu', False, 'Whether the job is executing on a TPU.')
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'tpu_name',
    default=None,
    help='Name of the Cloud TPU for Cluster Resolvers.')
flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'num_workers', 1, 'When num_workers > 1, training uses '
    'MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy. When num_workers = 1 it uses '
    'MirroredStrategy.')
flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'checkpoint_every_n', 1000, 'Integer defining how often we checkpoint.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('record_summaries', True,
                     ('Whether or not to record summaries defined by the model'
                      ' or the training pipeline. This does not impact the'
                      ' summaries of the loss values which are always'
                      ' recorded.'))

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


def main(unused_argv):
  flags.mark_flag_as_required('model_dir')
  flags.mark_flag_as_required('pipeline_config_path')
  tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)

  if FLAGS.checkpoint_dir:
    model_lib_v2.eval_continuously(
        pipeline_config_path=FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
        model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
        train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
        sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_examples,
        sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=(
            FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples),
        checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_dir,
        wait_interval=300, timeout=FLAGS.eval_timeout)
  else:
    if FLAGS.use_tpu:
      # TPU is automatically inferred if tpu_name is None and
      # we are running under cloud ai-platform.
      resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(
          FLAGS.tpu_name)
      tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
      tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
      strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
    elif FLAGS.num_workers > 1:
      strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
    else:
      strategy = tf.compat.v2.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

    with strategy.scope():
      model_lib_v2.train_loop(
          pipeline_config_path=FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
          model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
          train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
          use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
          checkpoint_every_n=FLAGS.checkpoint_every_n,
          record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

Please help me

**Full error trace**

```
(api) D:\happy_f>python Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=2000
2021-10-26 20:28:18.995443: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-10-26 20:28:18.999650: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-10-26 20:28:22.330709: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-10-26 20:28:22.334745: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2021-10-26 20:28:22.337735: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-10-26 20:28:22.342073: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: LAPTOP-M7GBQ78O
2021-10-26 20:28:22.344410: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: LAPTOP-M7GBQ78O
2021-10-26 20:28:22.346266: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-10-26 20:28:22.352251: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
WARNING:tensorflow:There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
W1026 20:28:22.355106  8376 cross_device_ops.py:1321] There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
I1026 20:28:22.355106  8376 mirrored_strategy.py:350] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\api\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\api\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\api\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 106, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\api\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 498, in train_loop
    configs = get_configs_from_pipeline_file(
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\api\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 138, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\api\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\api\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 103: invalid start byte
```

Comment: can you include the full error trace?

Comment: @BSP I included it.

Comment: The error is because there is some non-ascii character and it can not be encoded. Simple solution to avoid this error is by using `encode()`. Add this piece of code `x.encode('utf-8').strip()`. Thanks!